# Perform a second GET after login and redirect without getting kicked back to login page

Tags: python, python-requests

I can't share the specific URL I am trying to login to as it's an internally hosted service, and for that reason have removed details from the headers and data dictionaries, but they are working for login so I'm not having problems with them.

The site forces a redirect after login which is fine, but then seems unable to perform a second GET request and instead redirects me back to the login page. If I force it to not allow redirects, I'll just get an odd page that tells me the content I'm looking for isn't there anymore, so I assume it's losing my login. I've looked at a lot of prior answers and believe that my use of the session should maintain my login, session ID, cookies, headers, but obviously something else is going wrong. I'm wondering if I need to somehow acknowledge the redirect URL?

```
import requests
import urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings()

site_url="https://www.meow.com/login.asp" # this is my login url in the javascript form
base_url="https://www.meow.com"

headers = { } # accept, encoding, host, etc. that were in site headers
data = { } # username and password but also the other hidden fields the login form wanted

payload = "blah.asp?ID=1234"

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.get(base_url, verify=False, allow_redirects=True, timeout=20)

    p = s.post(site_url, data=data, verify=False, headers=headers)
    
    print(p.status_code)
    print(p.url)
    print(p.history)

    r = s.get(base_url, verify=False, allow_redirects=True, params=payload)
    
    print(r.status_code)
    print(r.url)
    print(r.history)
```

I am getting the following in response indicating it is successfully logging in and getting redirected to the home page, but then it keeps trying to redirect me to the login. I've tried several other pages on the site and get the same behavior (always redirected to login).

```
200
https://meow.com/home.asp
[<Response [302]>]
200
https://meow.com/login.asp
[<Response [302]>]
```

I know I could probably do all this with selenium but it seems like this should be possible with requests.

My end goal is to navigate to a "blah.asp?ID=1234&Export=True" and grab a CSV that should auto download. I think I can grab it with stream if I could actually navigate to the page.

Apologies for any mistakes I have made, I am very new to coding.

Comment: sounds like the service is not trusting the session ... maybe it just stores things in local javascript after login ... anyhow it likely impossible to give you an answer without knowing anything about the service ... if its proprietary maybe discuss with them how to do this ... or maybe try using selenium (that will basically act just like a browser(but introduces some hard bits of its own))

Answer (score 0):

Discovered my problem and thought I would post in case it helps someone else having the same problem.

The root problem was there was a mistake in my headers. I had assumed these were correct because it was logging in successfully, so I wanted to let future people know if you can login but can't navigate elsewhere, check your headers as it may not be required that they are accurate for the first GET, but need to be accurate in order to maintain session.

To get accurate headers (in Chrome) before you begin navigating, select the 3-dot menu top right, then developer tools. Then select the "Network" tab and navigate to your desired location. A lot of documents will then load. Scroll up and select the top document (usually). This will give you a "Request URL" and "Request Method" at the top (usually GET). Scroll down to "Request Headers". These items should be included in a header variable like so:

```
headers = {
"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9", 
"Cache-Control": "max-age=0", 
"Connection": "keep-alive"}
```

There might be a lot more these are just examples of what you'd expect to see.

If you need to do a login (like I did) you'll need login parameters, these were my "data" field above. They'll be formatted the same as the headers.

To get the data/login fields, navigate to your login page and right click and inspect. Depending on how the page is formatted, you're probably going to find a table with a URL (that may or may not be the page you would navigate to to login) with POST function, here's an example:

```
<form name="form" action="Login.asp?login=true" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
```

Inside that table you'll usually find your username and password fields, but you also might find hidden fields. For those you want "name" and "value" fields along with your username/password in your "data" group.

```
data = {'name': 'value', 'name': 'value', 'Username': 'yourusernamehere', 'Password': 'yourpasswordhere'}
```

Make sure your username/password fields have whatever capitalization the table is expecting.

Lastly, I stated I was trying to download an auto-downloading CSV. This navigated to a .asp page that then redirected to an AJAX page. I used a GET on the url that you would normally "click" to download (the first .asp page). Allow redirects, stream = true, and have a good timeout that it gives it enough time to get it. Then just capture it with open (no chunk-ing necessary):

```
    response = s.get(file_url, verify=False, allow_redirects=True, timeout=(45,45), stream=True)    

    open('whateverfilenameyouwant.csv', 'wb').write(response.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this**

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as session:
    login_obj = scrapLogin(email_id="email@gmail.com", 
                           user_id="123",
                           password="sYaTMru",
                           api_key="DDQWDWDY4",
                           session=session)

    login_status = login_obj.login()
```